# shell script to write the selected text to single line

Tags: shell, awk

Hi i have a log file trace.log which prints the time stamp, thread name and Transaction method and  transaction ID as below.

```
2014-01-23 15:50:41,724 [catalina-exec-35] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1308::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,725 [catalina-exec-33] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1304::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,727 [catalina-exec-10] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1298::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,727 [catalina-exec-24] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1307::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,727 [catalina-exec-12] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1305::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,733 [catalina-exec-10] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1298::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,734 [catalina-exec-26] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1313::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,734 [catalina-exec-26] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1313::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,738 [catalina-exec-39] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1311::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,733 [catalina-exec-35] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1308::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,738 [catalina-exec-27] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1309::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,737 [catalina-exec-22] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1310::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,743 [catalina-exec-30] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1315::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,744 [catalina-exec-39] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection DONE, ID=1311::
2014-01-23 15:50:41,747 [catalina-exec-2] INFO  TRANSACTION getConnection REQUEST, ID=1318::
```

i want to grep and print the time stamp of the  getConnection REQUEST and  getConnection DONE for a perticular ID in a single line into a file.

I have a written a shell script that printing the time stamp in multiple lines as below.
Here is my shell script

```
 for i in {1..800}
 do
      echo "Welcome $i times"
      echo "ID=$i, getConnection " >> time.log
      grep ID=$i: trace.log | grep getConnection | cut -d'[' -s -f1 >> time.log
 echo "      " >> time.log
 done
```

The output is as shown below

```
   ID=791, getConnection
   2014-01-23 15:50:16,703
   2014-01-23 15:50:16,706

   ID=792, getConnection
   2014-01-23 15:50:16,704
   2014-01-23 15:50:16,704

   ID=793, getConnection
   2014-01-23 15:50:16,704
   2014-01-23 15:50:16,709

   ID=794, getConnection
   2014-01-23 15:50:16,708
   2014-01-23 15:50:16,712
```

How i can do that? please help

I need output as shown below

```
ID=792, getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:16,703 2014-01-23 15:50:16,706

ID=792, getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:16,704 2014-01-23 15:50:16,704

ID=793, getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:16,704 2014-01-23 15:50:16,709

ID=794, getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:16,708 2014-01-23 15:50:16,712
```

Comment: Looping trough all number just to test if it exists is not needed.  You can store all in array and sort it out fro there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe to `tr` to remove the newline as shown below:

```
grep ID=$i: trace.log | grep getConnection | cut -d'[' -s -f1 | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Another change that would be required is to say `echo -n "ID=$i, getConnection " >> time.log` instead.

Comment: how to introduce space between two fields,2014-01-23 15:50:16 and 2014-01-23 15:50:16,706

Comment: you should get a space already because there is a space before `[`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can save some commands by changing this:

```
grep ID=$i: trace.log | grep getConnection | cut -d'[' -s -f1
```

to:

```
awk '$0~id && /getConnection/ {print $1,$2}' id=$i trace.log
2014-01-23 15:50:41,724
2014-01-23 15:50:41,733
```

---

Why not make `awk` do all (using your data):

```
awk -F" \\\[|=" '{split($3,i,":")} /getConnection REQUEST/ {r[i[1]]=$1} /getConnection DONE/ {d[i[1]]=$1} END {for (j in r) print "ID=" j " getConnection " r[j] "," d[j]}' file
ID=1318 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,747,
ID=1309 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,738,
ID=1298 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,727,2014-01-23 15:50:41,733
ID=1310 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,737,
ID=1311 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,738,2014-01-23 15:50:41,744
ID=1313 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,734,2014-01-23 15:50:41,734
ID=1304 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,725,
ID=1315 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,743,
ID=1307 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,727,
ID=1308 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,724,2014-01-23 15:50:41,733
```

---

Some change version and added `sort`

```
awk -F" \\\[|=" '{split($3,i,":")} g {/DONE/?d[i[1]]=$1:r[i[1]]=$1} END {for (j in r) print "ID="j,g,r[j]","d[j]}' g="getConnection" file | sort -k1
ID=1298 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,727,2014-01-23 15:50:41,733
ID=1304 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,725,
ID=1307 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,727,
ID=1308 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,724,2014-01-23 15:50:41,733
ID=1309 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,738,
ID=1310 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,737,
ID=1311 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,738,2014-01-23 15:50:41,744
ID=1313 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,734,2014-01-23 15:50:41,734
ID=1315 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,743,
ID=1318 getConnection 2014-01-23 15:50:41,747,
```